# Slides.js jQuery plugin not loading right in Chrome or Safari but fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slideshow

I am using this plugin: http://slidesjs.com/

When I load my website: http://26splitrockcove.com/ in Firefox, this slideshow loads and works perfectly as it should. However when I load this website in Chrome or Safari it doesn't show anything, not even the preloading image, however it will soon show the slides, however it always waits until the last (or third) image in the slideshow, then when it transitions the transitions aren't how they should be.

Now, the really weird thing is that this only happens when you reload the page using the reload button, however if you click on the url and hit enter, in both Safari and Chrome - it works perfectly.

This is my javascript for it:

```
$(function(){
        $('.home .slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'assets/loading.gif',
            autoHeight: true, //before I used this, it didn't even show the third image at all
            play: 5000,
            slideSpeed: 1000,
            effect: 'slide',
            pagination: false,
            generatePagination: false,
            pause: 150,
            hoverPause: true
        }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your markup, and it looks like you are forgetting some divs/classes.

**Your code:**

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="photos/510ad67ebdf9c_thumb.jpg"/>
        <img src="photos/510ad71697e59_thumb.jpg"/>
        <img src="photos/510ad697b3734_thumb.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What you should have:**

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div>
            <img src="photos/510ad67ebdf9c_thumb.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="photos/510ad71697e59_thumb.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="photos/510ad697b3734_thumb.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The slides js javascript looks for the "slides_container" div, and then sets the slides based on it's containing divs.

Source:[slidesjs.com](http://slidesjs.com)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it, but when I tried doing that it didn't fix it. But I did check, and I changed in the source code of the plugin from using `slides_container` to using `slideshow`, so that works fine. And when I add the divs it didn't do anything either.

Comment: I got it to work, I just had to use css and define the widths and heights of the slideshow and images... odd.